# How to wrap a 2D shape and Knife Project toward a cylinder axis?

Tags: 3d-printing, knife-tool

I'm trying to make a technical drawing of an air compressor nozzle for 3d printing.
[image]

Drawing the cylinder is trivial, but I cannot figure how to implement the cutout, or at least how to do it efficiently.

In my mind, I should draw a 2D version of the cutout shape, then somehow wrap it around the cylinder, and knife project it inward toward the cylinder axis.  But I can't find anything about Knife Project toward an axis (I found a YouTube video saying <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> would project toward a point / for a sphere?), and I don't know anything about wrapping a 2D shape around my cylinder.

Am I anywhere close to the right track?

Answer (score 5):

You could begin with a 2D shape:

[image]

Give it a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, 360° on Z:

[image]

Solidify, etc:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Start with half a cylinder then model the following. Duplicate and Rotate. Merge By Distance. Add a Solidify Modifier then Apply it. Add supporting loop cuts. And then Subdivision Modifier.

[image]